# RTSP stream in processing 3

Tags: processing

I am trying to display rtsp stream from an ip camera on processing 3 , vlc can display the stream and i tried opencv for processing but it didn't work the error says it failed to load gstreamer , any ideas ?

processing code :

```
import codeanticode.gsvideo.*;
import processing.video.*;
import codeanticode.syphon.*;

Capture myCapture;

GSPipeline pipe;

void setup() {
size(640,480, P2D);
pipe = new GSPipeline(this, "rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.200/mpeg4  ! rtpmp4vdepay ! ffdec_mpeg4"); 
pipe.play();
}

void draw() {
if (pipe.available()) {
pipe.read();
image(pipe, 0, 0);

}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for editing your question. Now can you post the full text of the error message, as well as which line it occurs on?